# MariaDB service won't start (mysqld.sock not found)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My last error.log Logfile is from the 08. July and the system won't create newer Logfiles.

```
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 4530292 and 4530292 in ibdata files do not mat
ch the log sequence number 5818903 in the ib_logfiles!
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
170708 13:55:34 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 4294896896 in space 0,
InnoDB: space name ./ibdata1,
InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.
InnoDB: Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type 10.
InnoDB: If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that
InnoDB: your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the
InnoDB: MySQL server.
2017-07-08 13:55:34 76fe3000  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 1996369920 in file fil0fil.cc line 5
612
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
170708 13:55:34 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.0.30-MariaDB-0+deb8u2
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=153
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 351246 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x30000
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Right now i tried to move the content from /var/lib/mysql to a fresly installed server with only MariaDB installed.

(Stop MariaDB Server -> backup /var/lib/mysql directory on new server > tar /var/lib/mysql directory from not working server > copy tar-file to new server >  extract > start MariaDB Server => Failed)

I have no clue what to do next - all i need is to backup a single database.

System:

- Raspbian (latest)
- MariaDB Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.30-MariaDB for debian-linux-gnueabihf

Looking forward for some help

Thanks in advance